# Flask - POST Error 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, http, post, flask

I'm just starting to learn Flask, and I am trying to create a form which will allow a **POST** method.

Here's my method:

```
@app.route('/template', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def template():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return("Hello")
    return render_template('index.html')
```

And my `index.html`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Title </title>
</head>

<body>
  Enter Python to execute:
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="expression" />
    <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Loading the form (rendering it when it receives **GET**) works fine. When I click on the **submit** button however, I get a `POST 405 error Method Not Allowed`.

Why isn't it displaying **"Hello"**?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55134621/4746570

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your form is submitting to `/` when the method is routed for `/template` unless that is a typo, you should adjust your form's `action` attribute to point at the `template` view: `action="{{ url_for('template') }}"`

Answer (score 17):

Replace:

```
 <form action="/" method="post">
```

with:

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('template') }}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 6):

If you omit the `action` attribute, the form will post to the current URL.

Replace:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

with:

```
<form method="post">
```