# How to print output using only a POST Method?

Tags: python, json, flask

How can I print something like this:

```
{
    username = admin
    email = admin@localhost
    id=42
}
```

With only using a `method = ['POST']` and without using `render_template`?

PS: I already made it run with `['GET']`

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return jsonify(username="admin",
                       email="admin@localhost",
                       id="42")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        return jsonify(username="admin",
                       email="admin@localhost",
                       id="42")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And what I get is a 405 Method error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey make sure your trailing stashes in your html are correct.

you may refer to : [Flask - POST Error 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179593/flask-post-error-405-method-not-allowed) and flask documentation : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/

this

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

and this is same same but different

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.

Given your error 405, I am suspecting that this is your problem. GET is fine, because you will just be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the form (as biobirdman said) on a GET request. Not sure why you need the `request.method == 'POST'` conditional statement. The parameter `methods=['POST']` in the route should suffice.

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    return jsonify(username="admin", email="admin@localhost", id="42")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def form():
    return "<form action='/' method='POST'>" \
            "<input type='submit'>" \
            "</form>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```