# AngularJs and web api PUT not working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to make a PUT request to a web api server, using the following.

Angular resource and request:

```
Books: $resource('/api/book/:id',
                {id: '@id'},
                {
                    'update' : {method: 'PUT'}
                })
...

$id = book.BookId
BookLibraryAPI.Books.update({id: $id},book);
```

Web API controller:

```
public void Put(int id, string book)
{

}
```

But I get 405 error, with the following headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:53889/api/book/1009
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
...
```

I tried many things, and I still cannot find the issue.

And the entire controller:

[Authorize]
public class BookController : ApiController
{
    BusinessBundle _bundle = new BusinessBundle();

```
// GET api/book
public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
{
    return _bundle.BookLogic.GetAll();
}

// GET api/book/5
public Book Get(int id)
{
    return _bundle.BookLogic.GetBook(id);
}

// POST api/book
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{

}

// PUT api/book/5
public void Put(int id, string book)
{
    var a = book; // just for testing
}

// DELETE api/values/5
public void Delete(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: please add the controller(all the cs)

Comment: Maybe because the `Put` expects two parameters, `id` & `book` and you're only sending one ?

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162825/web-api-put-request-generates-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error i think it may be the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something strikes me as strange, in .js you're doing the following :

```
$id = book.BookId
BookLibraryAPI.Books.update({id: $id},book);
```

Which means that book is a 'complex' object, but on the cs controller part you're receiving book as a string :

```
// PUT api/book/5
public void Put(int id, string book)
{
    var a = book; // just for testing
}
```

To start with, `book` cannot be a string since you're sending a full object. At worst it can be a generic object type, at best it should be a class with **exactly** the same members that you sent from the angular part.

So my suggestion is to make a class to match the `book` parameter you sent from the javascript.

ps: `Put()` on the asp.net controller does expect a second contrary to what was suggested in the above comments.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks a lot!
I had a class just like that. I was used to stringify-it, therefor the string argument.