# Okhttp Put method returning 'Method Not Allowed'

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, okhttp, http-status-code-405

I am attempting to call a put method on my server using OkHttp from an Android application.

**This is the api method signature:**

```
public void Put(int userId, string regId)
{
}
```

**This is the Android code to call the above method:**

```
private boolean SendGCMRegIdToServer(String registrationId, Integer userId) throws IOException {
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .host(serverApiHost)
            .addPathSegment("AppDashboard")
            .addPathSegment("api")
            .addPathSegment("GCM/")
            .build();

    MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    String json = "{'userId':" + userId + ","
            + "'regId':'" + registrationId + "'"
            + "}";

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .put(requestBody)
            .build();

    //this should post the data to my server
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if(response.code() == 400)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now the problem is I am getting the error code 405 in the response saying Method not allowed, but I cannot see where the problem is because I can successfully call the method using Postman on the server itself as below:

*http://localhost/AppDashboard/api/GCM?userId=5&regId=123*

I'm thinking it may have something to do with an integer or string being passed incorrectly in the JSON string, but cannot see why this isn't working.

Comment: are you sure you also use a PUT in postman?

Answer (score 1):

I see two different approaches in your REST api calls. In the one of OkHttp you send a PUT method with a JSON object serialized, and in POSTMAN you send a PUT (although I guess you do a GET) request with the parameters within the URL, I mean not in JSON body structure.

Anyway, `HTTP 405` is telling you that your backend does not support the PUT method, and probably it's [expecting a POST method](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx) with the `"X-HTTP-Method-Override:PUT"` HTTP header since POST is more standard method in REST than PUT.

What would I do is check your POSTMAN request carefully and adjust the one of Android to be the same method, parameters and headers, not more.

**Answer Update (as question has been updated)**

Of course there is a problem with that verb, as I said above IIS handles only the standard methods and PUT is not one of those. You have three choices:

1. Change your PUT to POST.
2. Use POST with X-HTTP-Method-Override to PUT. ([reference](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx))
3. Modify IIS config to support non standard REST methods. I
   personally wouldn't suggest the 3rd one, since it's attached to the
   backend config (e.g. imagine you change IIS to NancyFX).

Comment: So is there a way of sending an Okhttp put request without a body but with url parameters instead...

Comment: Sure, but why would you do that? I recommend to use JSON as everybody does. However, if you want to do that and use form parameters, adjust your MediaType and do something like this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-form-parameters

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and server was returning **405** . after some search i realized that is a configuration problem on **IIS** that does not let **put** requests. so there is no problem in android code and you should config your server to let this kind of requests.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162825/web-api-put-request-generates-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error) and [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1166025.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks for replies guys but seems I was getting a little confused between the two methods I was using to pass the params to my API.

**Here's what I did:**

changed the signature of the method to post with a param [FromBody] as a Model (only supports one paramater)...

```
public void Post([FromBody]UserGcmRegIdModel model)
{
}
```

I was then able to change my method call to the following using a nicer JSONBuilder and using .post in the request builder rather than .put

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("UserId", userId);
        jsonObject.put("RegId", registrationId);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
```

I still don't know if there is a problem with put() methods on IIS but using a post in my case was absolutely fine so I'm going with that...

Comment: I have updated my answer since your question has been updated too.