# ASP.NET Web API keeps returning a 405 'Method Not Allowed' status code when using HttpPut

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

On StackOverflow I saw a lot of people suggesting to change my web.config, so I changed it to this:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> 
</modules>
<handlers> 
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Yet I am still having the same problems as before. Any other suggestions? the method I am posting to is just a simple put

```
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/{user.Email}/", user);
```

In the API the method it's calling looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Account(string userName, JObject user)
{
    ....
}
```

Here is the route config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "IdentityApi", 
    routeTemplate: "{userName}/{action}/", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Identity", action = "Account" } 
);
```

Comment: Mayby this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207153/error-405-method-not-allow-when-calling-put-method-in-postman-with-body-parame/38207759#38207759

Comment: there is probably a way to do this without HttpPut anyway, but i'd love to see the answer too

Comment: Not sure how you `JObject` would work? How does it now to convert a user (as JSON) to JObject? Try getting down to basic by replacing `JObject user` with `string user` and then call the service with `client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/{user.Email}/", "testUserName")`

Comment: Also, could you update you question with you routing details

Comment: As per @AntoinePelletier comment, there is actually no difference on HttpPut and HttpPost. It is a question about semantic. See [PUT vs POST](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/)

Comment: I tried @Michael's suggestion but it still does not work. It keeps returning the 405 code

Comment: When I'm changing it to a post (so PostAsJsonAsync and HttpPost) I'm getting a 404 error

Comment: Please add your `MapHttpRoute` to your question

Comment: Do you mean this:

     `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "IdentityApi",
                    routeTemplate: "{userName}/{action}/",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Identity", action = "Account" }
                );`

Comment: Really just guessing here, but aren't you missing api from the routeTemplate: `"api/{userName}/{action}/"`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route template `routeTemplate: "{userName}/{action}/"` you are calling the wrong URL `api/{user.Email}/`.

The assumption here is that your `ApiController` looks like this

```
public class IdentityController : ApiController {
    [HttpPut]
    public void Account(string userName, JObject user) { .... }
}
```

You should update either your route template to match the URL you want

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "IdentityApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{userName}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Identity", action = "Account" } 
);
```

or the URL you are calling to match your original routeTemplate...

```
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"{user.Email}/", user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this in your web.config:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```