# MVC Web API pass both ID and POST-data to method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would like to have a PUT-method that i can call with:

```
localhost/api/editRole/id and pass post-data.
```

My route looks like this:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Then i tried the following method:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public bool editRole(int id, roleDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.editRole(postdata);
    }
```

but if i try to call `localhost/api/editRole/2` with some post-data i get The `requested resource does not support http method 'PUT`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where is your controller name in the url localhost/api/editRole/2 ?

Comment: @Vermillion check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502198/web-api-405-the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-put

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mark your arguments with `[FromUri]` and `[FromBody]` attributes correspondingly:

```
[HttpPut]
public bool editRole([FromUri] int id, [FromBody] roleDTO postdata)
{
    return dal.editRole(postdata);
}
```

Also your url `localhost/api/editRole/2` should be like `localhost/api/{controllerName}/2`