# "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have added Verb Attributes to method as described in previous questions
The url is simply http://192.168.1.66:51457/api/Home/4031.

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Put(int Username, [FromBody]Models.User Content)
{
    …
```

my web api route config is:

```
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

within the postman headers it returns : Allow → GET,POST
Hopefully this is enough information.

I'm sending this Json:

```
{
  "Email": null,
  "Password": null,
  "FirstName": null,
  "LastName": null,
  "Country": null,
  "PostCode": null,
  "MaxLocation": 0,
  "DOB": "2018-09-04T00:00:00",
  "MinAge": 30,
  "MaxAge": 31,
  "Gender": true
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502198/web-api-405-the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-put#25331236 ??

Comment: @stuartd ive tried that

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the attributes:

```
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
[HttpPut]
```

Comment: just as a test: try to rename your method and call it with the new name.