# Using VBScript to POST API call

Tags: post, vbscript, winhttp

I am not sure what I am missing.  I am trying to make a call to get a token returned via API.  I need this token to do further calls - like create users, etc.  Anyway, if I a similar call using GET to find the status, it works.  Also, if I use the same information in this code in FIDDLER, it works and returns a token.  Here is the Code:

Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

```
msgbox("body build")
sReqBody = "<Token>" &_
    "<Password>password</Password>" &_
    "<SiteCode>ABC1</SiteCode>" &_
    "<Username>Username1</Username>" &_
    "<Token>" 

msgbox("Building the POST")

sWebServiceURL ="http://testapi.releasecandidate-community360.net/api/token" 'Web Service URL
sWebhost =  "testapi.community360.net" 

msgbox (sWebServiceURL)
msgbox (sWebHost)

'POST the URL
oWinHttp.open "POST", "http://testapi.releasecandidate-community360.net/api/token", False
msgbox ("Set header")
'Set Header
oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Host", sWebHost
oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", ""

msgbox("sending")
oWinHttp.send sReqBody
msgbox(sReqBody)
oWinHttp.WaitForResponse(120)
sResponse = oWinHttp.ResponseText
wscript.echo sResponse
```

The error is 404 - File or directiry not found.

This makes no sense since I can find that directory and FIDDLER tool works fine.  I am guessing I need to talk to my Dev guys about the error messages we are returning.

But, any ideas what I am doing wrong with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Are manual and scripted request identical when you inspect them with Fiddler? If they're identical they should yield the same result. Also, you shouldn't need `WaitForResponse`, since you made the request synchronous.

Comment: After removing `/api/token` from `sWebServiceURL` I got the other error [405 = HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how). HTH. Adjusted `sWebServiceURL = "http://testapi.releasecandidate-community360.net"` and then used as follows: `oWinHttp.open "POST", sWebServiceURL, False`