# 405-Method Not allowed for the HTTP Post in ASP.Net Web Api 2.0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net Web Api 2.

I have almost gone through more than 10-15 links including MSDN but still issue persists, hence posting this question.

```
 <system.webServer>
 <handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>

      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers:" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method:" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />

    </customHeaders>

</httpProtocol>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

- Added above configuration in my *web.config*
- Installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`
- Decorated my class with `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

Now I have published this to IIS and trying to access the services from JavaScript/jQuery. However, HTTP `Get` is returning **success**(as desired) but HTTP `Post` is returning the below error:

> HTTP 405-Method not allowed

What should I do to fix this error for the HTTP `Post` or `PUT`?

```
//jQuery ajax call
$.ajax(
{
   url : "http://myip:myport/api/Customer
   type : "POST",
   data: {'custName' : name},
   success : function(e)
   {

   },
  error: function(e)
  {
  }
})
```

My class:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private static List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        namesList.Add("Chetan");
        return namesList;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(string name)
    {
        namesList.Add(name);
        return;
    }
}
```

**routes.config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Below link doesn't suffice the question. I already have tried with it.
 [Asp.NET Web API - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed - how to set handler mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how)

Comment: Have you previously released the same application with POST not allowed? If so, you might be getting a cached version of your site. This happened to me and fought it for hours, until I ran Ccleaner.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath.. no I haven't done anything such

Comment: Have you tried decorating your method with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath.. intially I got Cross orgin exception whilc trying to consume any of the service then I enabled cross orgin, after that HTTP Get is returing success but HTTP Post is throwing 405 error

Comment: No I have not decorated my  action with [HTTPPost], is it needed??

Comment: It sure won't hurt to try.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath.. checked with `[HTTPPost]` still same error

Comment: @Chetan BTW, please edit your question and add the calling method as well as web api controller name and action name.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath... added

Comment: @JimG... did all that...

Comment: @Chetan one last thing, please post your RouteConfig, I forgot in my last comment

Comment: @cFrozenDeath.. added

Comment: In **WebApiConfig**, change your routetemplate to: "api/{controller}/{acttion}/{id}" and change your ajax call to http://myip:myport/api/Customer/post/. Let's see what happens

Comment: @cFrozenDeath.. still same 405 Error