# ASP.net WebApi POST returns 405 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular5

I'm building Angular 5 app with asp.net backend. I want to send POST request, I tested it via Postman and it works absolutely fine, however, when I try to do it inside Angular I get 405 error.
I user HttpClient with headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), same as Postman.

I tried to change web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

but it seems it does not work.

Angular POST code (with headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })

```
   setDopuskItem(itemToSave: DopuskItem){
     let endpoint = this._dopuskApiUrl + 'set';
     let body = JSON.stringify(itemToSave);

     return this.http.put(
      endpoint,
      body,
      httpOptions)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55134621/4746570

Answer (score 1):

it's because the browsers send preflight request before send main request.

you can add following code to your webapi app: global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```