# ASP.Net Controller method not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

I'm learning web.api from asp.net. The problem is, my delete and put method not working right now. I think there's something wrong with my code :*

**Here's my controller for delete:**

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteLocation(Guid id)
    {
        Location location = _locationRepository.GetSingle(e => e.Id == id);
        if (location == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _locationRepository.Delete(location);


        return Ok(location);
    }
```

**and these are my put:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LocationViewModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutLocation(Guid id, LocationViewModel location)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != location.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        location.Id = id;

        try
        {
            await _locationRepository.EditAsync(location.ToModel());
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!LocationExist(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

This confusing me..
My get and post things works perfectly.
I'm using postman to test the method and it said:
[image]

405 method not allowed.. and I have no idea. And these are my generic repository. maybe something wrong with this too..

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :IGenericRepository<T> where T : class,ISoftDelete where C : DbContext, new()
//public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, ISoftDelete
{
    //protected readonly ShopDiaryProject.EF.ShopDiaryDbContext _entities;

    private C _entities = new C();
    public C Context
    {

        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }


    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(i => i.IsDeleted == false);

        return query;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(i => i.IsDeleted == false).Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public virtual T GetSingle(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        T data = _entities.Set<T>().Where(i => i.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        return data;
    }

    public virtual bool Add(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            this.Save();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().AddRange(entity);
            this.Save();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.IsDeleted = true;
            entity.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
            Edit(entity);
            this.Save();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Edit(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            this.Save();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private bool _disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _entities.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match)
    {
        return _entities.Set<T>().Count(match);
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await this.SaveAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().AddRange(entity);
            await this.SaveAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.IsDeleted = true;
            entity.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
            Edit(entity);
            await this.SaveAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> EditAsync(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await this.SaveAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    return false;
        //}
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> SaveAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _entities.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {

                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Maybe someone here can help me :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly you have to enable it via web.config or via owin to allow the said methods you plan to use. Also `POST != PUT`

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#http-methods):

> Web API also selects actions based on the HTTP method of the request (GET, POST, etc). By default, Web API looks for a case-insensitive match with the start of the controller method name. For example, a controller method named PutCustomers matches an HTTP PUT request.
>
> You can override this convention by decorating the method with any the following attributes:
>
> - [HttpDelete]
> - [HttpGet]
> - [HttpHead]
> - [HttpOptions]
> - [HttpPatch]
> - [HttpPost]
> - [HttpPut]

So for your `Delete` method:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteLocation(Guid id)
{
}
```

And from Postman set method to `Delete` and url to `http://localhost:xxxx/api/Locations/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`

For your `Put` method:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(LocationViewModel))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutLocation(Guid id, LocationViewModel location)
{
}
```

And from Postman set method to `Put` and url to `http://localhost:xxxx/api/Locations/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`

Comment: Still not working.. 
http://shopdiary.funcraftstudio.com/api/Locations/97ecf0f5-c177-4844-b467-0caf2cbc11b5
still 405 method not allowed

Comment: Still not working.. http://shopdiary.funcraftstudio.com/api/Locations/97ecf0f5-c177-4844-b467-0caf2cbc11b5 still 405 method not allowed

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteLocation(Guid id) << is this thing causing problem?

And I use this route for post:
http://localhost:8080/api/Locations/PostLocation

Comment: You may need to verify your IIS is configured to accept DELETE method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how

Answer (score 1):

can you add `[HttpDelete]`  on your delete method , so it get identified as delete action verb

```
[HttpDelete]
[ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteLocation(Guid id)
{
```

Comment: That is right but .NET also identifies the HTTP verb from the name of the Action, in this case, DeleteLocation should be identified as a valid endpoint accepting DELETE verb.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is **Delete** at **Put** verbs are not allowed by IIS or IIS Express by default. So you should replace the  tag content to the following content in your web.config file.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

//This will enable all Web API verbose
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the webdavModule at web.config . And It works!

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```