# 405 - http verb used to access this page is not allowed iis in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, http, post, redirect, iis

I am getting this error when my payment gateway is redirecting user to my react application. Same code works on firebase hosting and doesn't give the error. Redirection url is a POST request

I tried various solutions from [Asp.NET Web API - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed - how to set handler mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how)

removed WebDav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is no CORS issue here.

The issue is the call back to your site is a Post request along with data. Client application's index.html hosted inside IIS is not able to understand how to handle a post request to a html page. You will have to specifically make an entry in Handler Mapping section of IIS configurations.

[image]

Inside Request Restrictions add the HTTP Methods you want it for or allow all verbs if it is a specific case.

[image]

Or you can directly put it in your web.config with what all verbs you want to allow, as in below snippet

```
    <add name="html" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On the **Request Filtering** page, switch to the "**HTTP Verbs**" tab - if you see that "POST" has "**Allowed**" set to False, this is the cause. Remove this entry or changing it to explicitly be allowed will fix the issue.

Comment: thank you but We have already tried with this solution still it is showing same result