405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed error in windows server PHP
I tried everything but I could not figure out what the problem is.When I want to send Delete request it turns with an error says 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed error.
I changed my web.config file. I guess the problem is WebDAV.I can send GET and POST requests.  I deleted My currently not working file is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="UserPageRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/user-page.php?username={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>


        <rule name="ProductPageRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^p/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/product.php?slug={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>


        <rule name="PHPFileAccess" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([^.]+)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
        </rule>


        <rule name="Custom404" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/404.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>


  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\techarsiv.com\tmp" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

My whole app is php but my the server I bought is windows.And they don't let me change configuration from ISS .What should I do for solving this issue ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915817/405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-iis-in-reactjs-app might be of some help. Plesk also has a help page for this issue

UnfortunatelyI can not access (IIS) Manager .

You might need to contact your host, then, to have them check the options.

It looks like you've already tried removing the WebDAV module and handler from your configuration. In addition, you can also try setting Allow Verb Filtering to false. Something like this: https://i.sstatic.net/LH4Ctudr.png
