# 405 HTTP Error on submitting data on PHP / HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am building a form that the filled data need to be sent to an email. I am using HTML and PHP. But Unfortunately I get the following error when I press SUBMIT button.

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access

The PHP code is :

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $email_subject = "NEW MESSAGE VIA CONTACT FORM";
    
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user ".$name. ".\n".$message;
    
    $to = "info@house.gr"
    $headers = "From: ".$visitor_email;
    
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
}
?>
```

The HTML form is :

```html
<form method="POST" class="contact-form" actions="contactform.php">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Phone">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail">
                                <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
                            </form>
```

**UPDATE:** with this edit on code: action="contactform.php" , I dont get the error but the email is not send

**FINAL SOLUTION:**
Changed the php file to this:

```html
    $headers = "From: ";
    $headers .= $visitor_email;
    
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    header('Location: ../');
```

I found the problem via the log files in the webserver

Comment: Typically, a 405 error means you are sending a request to an endpoint that doesn't know how to handle that request type. Make sure you are directing to the right endpoint and that it is set up to handle POST requests.

Comment: @TheHeadRush how can i check this? I followed many tutorials and they did the same thing

Comment: No idea. I haven't worked with PHP in like 20 years. Presumably you have a controller method that maps to the `Location: index.html?mailsend` request. If so, check that it handles POST requests. If not, make a handler that does.

Comment: Are you using IIS? Quick searches for that specific error message detail are showing that you might need [disable WebDAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854860/231316) or possibly just allow POST to that file type.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am running through the server directly so i am not sure WebDAV is smth I can adjust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you wrote actions instead of action in the form's attribute

```
actions="contactform.php"
```

should be

```
action="contactform.php"
```

Comment: Now i dont get the error but the email is not send

Comment: @TheGame then go check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail